# express js route matching url that doesn't start with a string

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I want my route to match URL that doesn't start with "/api/"

For example, "/", "/home", "/profile" will trigger the route, but "/api/user/get" and "/api/xx" will not.

I have tried the following regular expression and its modifications:

```
app.get('/^(?!api)', function(req, res) {})
```

Comment: I can't see why people are downvoting this. If you are going to downvote, at least give a reason why

Answer (score 3):

This kind of router organization is usually not solved with regex's in
the route matching, but rather with the concepts of routers and default
matching.

The router concept allows you to organize your routes into logical
units, such as a file that contains your API routes and file that
contains your other routes.

The default route matches routes that haven't already been matched.

So in your case you might have a main app that includes a router for the
API calls, a router for other calls, and then a default route that
matches everything else.

The default route is usually used to return a 404, but you could use it
to capture "all routes that don't begin with "/api", realizing that *no*
pages would 404.

Here's some working skeleton code to illustrate:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// The "non-API Router is likely to exist in a separate file
var nonAPIrouter = express.Router();

// More routes unrelated to APIs
//nonAPIRouter.get();

//////////////////////////////////////////

// The API router may be in it's own file, too.
var APIrouter = express.Router();

// Routes that start with /API
APIrouter.get('/api*', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello API!');
});
///////////////////////////////////////


// The main app includes both routers.
app.use(APIrouter);
app.use(nonAPIrouter);

// Default route for requests not matched above
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).end('error');
});



app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Mark's answer pointed me to Router(), that helped me come up with a solution. It may not be elegant, but it works for me. I defined a middleware and do regex (I simplified to /a) there. If it's no match then do its job, otherwise pass over to /a/***

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.url.match(/\/a\/*/g)) {
            res.sendFile('index.html'));
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    });

    var router = express.Router();
    router.get(...)
    router.post(...)
    app.use('/a', router);
```